# What does ‘One’ in “Detectives slapped handcuffs on her. “You know you did it,” she said one later shouted at her. “Just admit it.” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns

I felt the article of New York Times N.Y. Region section (July 25) titled “A Revenge Plot So Intricate, the Prosecutors Were Pawns” reporting a woman being framed by her boyfriend into the charge with carrying out a series of armed robberies very intriguing. But I was hung up on one minor point – the function of the word, ‘*one*’ in the following sentence of the article:

> “One night, Ms. Sumasar was pulled over by the police. Before she could speak, detectives slapped handcuffs on her. “You know you did it,” she said *one* later shouted at her. “Just admit it.”

What does ‘*one*’ here mean? Does it mean ‘one of the detectives’ or ‘*a* second later’? I am confused.

Comment: A poorly written sentence in a [fascinating story](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/07/26/nyregion/a-revenge-plot-so-intricate-the-prosecutors-were-pawns.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It stands for *one of the detectives*. This sentence is poorly constructed, because it is difficult to parse; but it is syntactically correct. The conjunction *that* has been omitted (which is fine in itself).

> “One night, Ms. Sumasar was pulled over by the police. Before she could speak, detectives slapped handcuffs on her. “You know you did it,” she said **that** one **detective** later shouted at her. “Just admit it.”

In a simpler sentence, this construction would be fine, because then there'd be no cause for confusion:

> The picture she said I had stolen was in her attic.

Comment: I'd actually rewrite it as *She said that one detective later shouted at her, "You know you did it. Just admit it."*

Comment: ＠Malvolio / @Martha. I was relieved to find your comments, because I suspected if 'one later shouted at her’ in this sentence is taken for granted to any native speakers, allowing no room for questioning.

Comment: @Martha: Right, you could do that. It would change word order but make it much more readable.

Comment: @Yoichi-san, I wouldn't worry that we find it that easy to read! The reason I don't find "a second" as easy to substitute as a possible meaning is that I must fill in a _lot_ of other words to make it work: "one moment later he shouted at her," for example. My mind does fill these in at first - I might find the same meaning on a first read - but if read carefully and force myself not to fill in any seemingly missing words, "detective" is the only "one" that works.